# I have issues with Google Analytics Data API (GA4) in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a problem, I can't get the call to analytics to work with the example from this documentation ( [Quick start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries?hl=en) ). I've changed some things I've read, since it doesn't allow me to use the example as it is, things like the

`'using Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta;'` or the part `'BetaAnalyticsDataClient client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.Create();'` I think it no longer works. Does anyone have it working? This is my code:

```
 using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta;
//////

// Google Analytics 4 property ID.
 string propertyId = "407521144";

 // Credential Path
 string credentialsPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") + @"Scripts\mktwebsuitedigital-afe56dbd25f6.json";


 // Authenticate and create the service.
 GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialsPath);
 AnalyticsDataService service = new AnalyticsDataService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "Google Analytics 4",
 });

 RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest
 {
     Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
     Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "city" }, },
     Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "activeUsers" }, },
     DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "2023-03-31", EndDate = "today" }, },
 };
 RunReportResponse response = service.Properties.RunReport(request, propertyId).Execute();
 // Make the request
         
 Console.WriteLine("Report result:");
 foreach (Row row in response.Rows)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row.DimensionValues[0].Value, row.MetricValues[0].Value);
 }
```

I have tried this code and other variants I have researched, like the one I posted, but I can't find a way. I know the part with the analytics id and the JSON is correct. It always fails with a

> System.NullReferenceException: 'null object' error on the line 'RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest'.

Comment: "I think it no longer works" - it's the opposite, I believe - the quick start is for the more recent package of Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta, and I suspect you're using the older Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta package.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've got in the question is for the older `Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta` library. The more modern library used in the quickstart (and linked from the "Install the client library" step) is the more recent [Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta) library, which will use gRPC+protos rather than HTTP/1.1+JSON by default.

If you change your dependency to use `Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta`, I'd expect the existing Quickstart code to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample you should be using `BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder`

```
using Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta;
using GoogleAnalyticsGa4Helpers;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, Google Analytics data api, Service account!");

// Path to the service account credentials file. 
const string credentialsJsonPath = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\ServiceAccountCred.json";

// Property on Google analytics which the service account has been granted access to.
const string propertyId = "250796939";

var client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = credentialsJsonPath
}.Build();

var metricFilter = new FilterExpression()
{  
    Filter = new Filter()
    { FieldName = "totalUsers",
        NumericFilter = new Filter.Types.NumericFilter()
        {
            Operation = Filter.Types.NumericFilter.Types.Operation.GreaterThan,
            Value = new NumericValue() { DoubleValue = 40 }
        }
    }
};

var dimensionFilter = new FilterExpression()
{  
    Filter = new Filter()
    { 
        FieldName = "country",
        StringFilter = new Filter.Types.StringFilter()
        {
            CaseSensitive = false,
            MatchType = Filter.Types.StringFilter.Types.MatchType.BeginsWith,
            Value = "u"
        }
    }
};

var request = new RunReportRequest
{
    Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
    Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "date" }, new Dimension() { Name = "country"} },
    Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "totalUsers" }, new Metric { Name = "newUsers" } },
    DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "2021-04-01", EndDate = "today" }, },
    MetricFilter = metricFilter,
    DimensionFilter = dimensionFilter,
    OrderBys = { new OrderBy() { Metric = new OrderBy.Types.MetricOrderBy() { MetricName = "newUsers"}}}
};

var response = await client.RunReportAsync(request);

// Helper Method
response.PrintToConsole();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Where GoogleAnalyticsGa4Helpers, BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder came from?

Comment: That is just a helper file I have

Answer (score 0):

Well, the current oficial google documentation is not working, but this worked for me:

```
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta;
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(YourPathToJsonFile);
var service = new AnalyticsDataService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });
```

And then for example:

```
RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest()
        {

            Property = $"properties/{YourPropertyId}",

            DateRanges = new List<DateRange>
            {
                new DateRange()
                {
                    StartDate = YourStartDate,
                    EndDate = YourEndDate
                }
            },

            Dimensions = new List<Dimension>
            {
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "eventName"
                },
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "customEvent:store_names"
                },
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "platform"
                }
            },

            Metrics = new List<Metric>
            {
                new Metric()
                {
                    Name = "activeUsers"
                },
                new Metric()
                {
                    Name = "eventCount"
                }
            },

            DimensionFilter = new FilterExpression()
            {
                AndGroup = new FilterExpressionList()
                {
                    Expressions = new List<FilterExpression>()
                    {
                        new FilterExpression()
                        {
                            Filter = new Filter()
                            {
                                FieldName = "eventName",
                                StringFilter = new StringFilter()
                                {
                                    Value = "stores"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new FilterExpression()
                        {
                            Filter = new Filter()
                            {
                                FieldName = "customEvent:type",
                                StringFilter = new StringFilter()
                                {
                                    Value = "enter"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Execute request.
        RunReportResponse response = await service.Properties.RunReport(request, propertyId).ExecuteAsync();
```

**EDIT:** **The documentation is ok**. My solution applies when you use Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta instead of the pre-released version

Comment: "Well, the current oficial google documentation is not working" - can you clarify in what way you believe it's broken? As per my answer, I believe it's a matter of the OP trying to use the wrong library with the quickstart code. If you believe the quickstart code doesn't work with the library linked in the quickstart, please could you give more details so we can fix it?

Comment: @jonSkeet sorry you are right, the documentation is ok. Since the newer one is a pre-released version, is it reliable to use on Production?

Comment: The version number is pre-production, but only because the API itself is beta and we avoid releasing GA versions for beta APIs. (We're more careful with that in the new libraries than the old ones.) Once there's a V1 API, we'll release a stable library.